# How to open PDF using the BASE64 key in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sapui5

I have seen a number of references to open the PDF using the base64. Nothing is working for me.

I tried using `window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64data);` but it's just showing the empty page in the browser.

I can able to view the pdf if I keep the base64data in `iFrame` tag. For my requirement, I need to open this PDF in the new tab.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs#Common_problems: _“Security issues:
A number of security issues (e.g. phishing) have been associated with data URLs, and navigating to them in the browser's top level. To mitigate such issues, top-level navigation to data:// URLs has been blocked in Firefox 59+ (release version, Nightly/Beta from 58), and we hope to see other browsers follow suit soon.”_

Comment: Did you check the console?  *Always* check the console.  `Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:application/pdf;base64,...`

Comment: ya. I was getting this message in the console. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
let pdfWindow = window.open("")
pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, " + encodeURI(base64data) + "'></iframe>")
```