# How to show Base64 image on browser's new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, browser, base64

I have Base64 encoded image as response, how can I show that image in new tab of browser using js? anybody can suggest a solutions. Thanks

```
 success: function (base64Image) {


         }
```

Comment: I don't know or it good, but you can save Base64 like a text to LocalStorage and convert back when it needed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open PDF using the BASE64 key in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61889128/how-to-open-pdf-using-the-base64-key-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Supposing you are going to get a GIF image:

```js
// Display a base64 URL inside an iframe in another window.
function debugBase64(base64URL){
    var win = window.open();
    win.document.write('<iframe src="' + base64URL  + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
}

success: function (base64Image) {

    // e.g This will open an image in a new window
    debugBase64("data:image/gif;base64," + base64Image);

    // you can try with this base64 (it is a red dot)
    // debugBase64("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP8AAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=");

}
```

Otherwise just change `data:image/gif;` with the right MIME type you need.

You can find a complete list here https://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

I found and I just tried this solution from https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/682/what-does-the-not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url-javascript-exception-means-in-google-chrome

Comment: OP asked *"in browser new tab"* - you can't use `data:` in a url, but there is a way around it

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889193/2181514 (wouldn't expect you to find that though :) )

Comment: Thanks for response! but my file is not pdf but image. @freedomm-m

Comment: I am getting this error: 'http://localhost/controller/action:1194 Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA' when I am using window.open("data:image/gif;base64," + base64Image) @FrancescoOrsi

Comment: someone else maybe found a solution https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/682/what-does-the-not-allowed-to-navigate-top-frame-to-data-url-javascript-exception-means-in-google-chrome

Comment: It working fine in Firefox but not working properly in chrome!  @FrancescoOrsi

Comment: @Asif I tried on Chrome, try to copy and paste this code in Chrome console, it works for me:

function debugBase64(base64URL){
    var win = window.open();
    win.document.write('<iframe src="' + base64URL  + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
}

debugBase64("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP8AAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=");

Comment: What if you really can't force only the use of images? What about a pdf, or any other mime types that can't display on an iframe? I can compose those with their correct data:application/pdf;base64 (i.e.) .. but would they get downloaded instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
let image = new Image();
image.src = "you-base64-encoded-image";
var newTab = window.open();
newTab.document.body.innerHTML = image.outerHTML;
```